# Event Grid webhook handshake validation failed

Tags: azure-eventgrid

Trying to register an event grid webhook subscription towards a traffic manager endpoint

```
New-AzureRmEventGridSubscription -EventSubscriptionName "{yours}" -EndpointType webhook -ResourceId /subscriptions/{yours}/resourceGroups/{yours}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/{yours} -Endpoint https://{yours}
```

fails with:

```
New-AzEventGridSubscription: Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'Webhook validation handshake failed for https://arg-int-nt.arg-int.core.windows.net/. Http POST request failed with response code Unknown.For troublehooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service should be online and responsive, your controller should return OK.
You need to append the **/yourcontroller/yourpath** suffix

```
New-AzureRmEventGridSubscription -EventSubscriptionName "{yours}" -EndpointType webhook -ResourceId /subscriptions/{yours}/resourceGroups/{yours}/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/{yours} -Endpoint https://{yours}/{yourcontroller}/{yourpath}*
```